# EclipseLink Query - Select count(*) from student s not working

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I am getting following exception :-

**[13, 13] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
[14, 14] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.**

Please help me analyse the problem.

P.S. If I replace the above query in my code with select * from student s, it is working fine.

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select count(*) from Student s ]. 
    [13, 13] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
    [14, 14] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select count(*) from Student s ]. 
    [13, 13] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
    [14, 14] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.core.commons.domain.util.reference.repository.AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.createQuery(AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.java:146)
        at com.core.commons.domain.util.reference.repository.AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.getTotalRecordsCount(AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.java:117)
        at com.core.commons.domain.util.reference.repository.AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.findBy(AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.java:48)
        at com.wfm.ft.service.FinancialTransactionServiceImpl.getAllBillingAccounts(FinancialTransactionServiceImpl.java:157)
        at com.wfm.ft.web.FTEntryController.getAllBillingAccounts(FTEntryController.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilter(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.AssociatedPartiesCallChecker.doFilter(AssociatedPartiesCallChecker.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.AdminUrlCallChecker.doFilter(AdminUrlCallChecker.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.BEMatcherFilter.doFilter(BEMatcherFilter.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.HttpCreateProcessContextFilter.doFilter(HttpCreateProcessContextFilter.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.HttpSecuredAccessDataExtractor.doFilter(HttpSecuredAccessDataExtractor.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.CreateSystemUserContextFilter.doFilter(CreateSystemUserContextFilter.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.web.SimpleCORSFilter.verifyRequestAndProcess(SimpleCORSFilter.java:183)
        at com.core.commons.service.web.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:83)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.TenantProcessContextFilter.doFilter(TenantProcessContextFilter.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select count(*) from Student s ]. 
    [13, 13] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
    [14, 14] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
        ... 84 more
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select count(ax) from ( select gle.glAccount.accountId as accountId, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name as accountName, gle.glAccount.accountType as accountType,gle.amount.currency.symbol as symbol ,sum(gle.amount.value * gle.postingTypeValue) as totalSum from GLEntry gle group by gle.glAccount.id, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name, gle.glAccount.accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol,gle.glAccount.id ) ax]. 
[22, 399] '(select gle.glAccount.accountId as accountId, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name as accountName, gle.glAccount.accountType as accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol as symbol, sum(gle.amount.value * gle.postingTypeValue) as totalSum from GLEntry gle group by gle.glAccount.id, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name, gle.glAccount.accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol, gle.glAccount.id) ax' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select count(ax) from ( select gle.glAccount.accountId as accountId, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name as accountName, gle.glAccount.accountType as accountType,gle.amount.currency.symbol as symbol ,sum(gle.amount.value * gle.postingTypeValue) as totalSum from GLEntry gle group by gle.glAccount.id, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name, gle.glAccount.accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol,gle.glAccount.id ) ax]. 
[22, 399] '(select gle.glAccount.accountId as accountId, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name as accountName, gle.glAccount.accountType as accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol as symbol, sum(gle.amount.value * gle.postingTypeValue) as totalSum from GLEntry gle group by gle.glAccount.id, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name, gle.glAccount.accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol, gle.glAccount.id) ax' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.core.commons.domain.util.reference.repository.AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.createQuery(AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.java:134)
    at com.core.commons.domain.util.reference.repository.AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.getTotalRecordsCount(AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.java:109)
    at com.core.commons.domain.util.reference.repository.AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.findBy(AbstractSearchCriteriaSupportRepositoryImpl.java:48)
    at com..ft.service.FinancialTransactionServiceImpl.getAllBillingAccounts(FinancialTransactionServiceImpl.java:157)
    at com..ft.web.FTEntryController.getAllBillingAccounts(FTEntryController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilter(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.AssociatedPartiesCallChecker.doFilter(AssociatedPartiesCallChecker.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.AdminUrlCallChecker.doFilter(AdminUrlCallChecker.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.BEMatcherFilter.doFilter(BEMatcherFilter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.HttpCreateProcessContextFilter.doFilter(HttpCreateProcessContextFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.HttpSecuredAccessDataExtractor.doFilter(HttpSecuredAccessDataExtractor.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.CreateSystemUserContextFilter.doFilter(CreateSystemUserContextFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.web.SimpleCORSFilter.verifyRequestAndProcess(SimpleCORSFilter.java:183)
    at com.core.commons.service.web.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at com.core.commons.service.security.filter.TenantProcessContextFilter.doFilter(TenantProcessContextFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select count(ax) from ( select gle.glAccount.accountId as accountId, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name as accountName, gle.glAccount.accountType as accountType,gle.amount.currency.symbol as symbol ,sum(gle.amount.value * gle.postingTypeValue) as totalSum from GLEntry gle group by gle.glAccount.id, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name, gle.glAccount.accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol,gle.glAccount.id ) ax]. 
[22, 399] '(select gle.glAccount.accountId as accountId, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name as accountName, gle.glAccount.accountType as accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol as symbol, sum(gle.amount.value * gle.postingTypeValue) as totalSum from GLEntry gle group by gle.glAccount.id, gle.glAccount.qualifier.name, gle.glAccount.accountType, gle.amount.currency.symbol, gle.glAccount.id) ax' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
    ... 84 more
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `select count(s) from Student s`.

Comment: I used the same in actual scenario but still getting some exception. Please check the UPDATE 1.

P.S. It worked in simple queries like select count(ax) from GLEntry ax.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think the exception is rather self explanatory. JPQL parser treats `(*)` as arithmetic operator thus it expects two operands within parentheses to perform multiplication.

In order to make query string work you would need to add *path expressions* that refer to student's state fields, i.e.

```sql
-- dummy example
SELECT COUNT(s.age * s.height) FROM Student s
```

---

If you are interested with EclipseLink's implementation you can go deeper and take a closer look at [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate](https://github.com/chenjiafan/eclipselink/blob/a1a6cfa35417931430bf2f4e3220d9ed72a2d6c2/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/jpql/HermesParser.java#L321) method where grammatical and semantic validation starts.